# Connect to sql through java

Tags: java, mysql, database, connection

I try to connect to SQL DB through java. When i run the code, in the console is printed: Connecting to database... then nothing happens and i have to stop the program.

```
package javasqltest;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class JavaSQLTest {

    static final String JDB_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:1527/";

    static final String USER = "test";
    static final String PASS = "test";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {          
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

            System.out.println("Creating database...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "CREATE DATABASE STUDENTS";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Database created successfully...");
        } catch (SQLException se) {          
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {          
            try {
                if (stmt != null) {
                    stmt.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException se2) {
            }
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    }
}
```

Any help for fixing this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

LE:

If i change the port to 3306 this is the console output:

```
run:
Connecting to database...
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
Goodbye!
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:355)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2461)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at javasqltest.JavaSQLTest.main(JavaSQLTest.java:27)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:305)
    ... 15 more
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: For what it's worth, it's not customary to create entire databases like this; you usually do that with management tools externally. The program will often manipulate *tables* within a database.

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL JDBC connection URL usually looks something like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname
```

where `dbname` is the name of your MySQL database, and `3306` is the default port on which MySQL is listening.  If your MySQL be really listening on port `1527` then you can use that instead.  You never specified the name of a database, and this alone would cause the connection to fail.

Comment: Hello Tim and thank you, i created the DB through Netbeans IDE and that was the default port that appeared. Even if i modify the URL to /localhost:1527/sqltest the result is the same. I followed the tutorial on tutorialspoint, but i don't understand why it stops there with no error.

Comment: Find out which port MySQL is actually using.

Comment: If i switch the port to 3306 i get an error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. so i think the port 1527 is ok. How can i find out the port used by MySQL?

Comment: In services tab the db name appears like this: jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/SQLTest [test on TEST]

Comment: Is there really no exception at all? This seems unlikely.

Comment: It's probably 1527, use that.  Is there an exception using port 1527?

Comment: Yes it's 1527 but i don't get any exception, nothing, the program keeps running until i manually stop it

Comment: @FlorinIcs Are you certain that you are using the correct username and password?

Comment: Yes, but as i see, if i change the username/password i still get no error, and it behaves like in the beginning when i have to stop it manually.

Comment: I still can't solve this problem, still no one knows? Even if the user/pass is wrong how can see that? Or is there some other kind of try/catch block that could get the incorrect inputs?